# Error accessing a ‘std::deque’ from an iteration of a ‘std::map’ that has as its second member the element that contains as attribute 'std::deque'

Tags: c++

I got a problem where the console return me a wrong output when I try to access to the pointers inside of an attribute 'std::deque' from an object inside of a structure 'std::map' as a second element in a double iterarion.

When I try to access to the memory position of the object company it return me the exact number of memory positions of the routes that I update on the 'std::deque'

This code:

```
for(auto& it_airlines : this->airlines){
        std::cout << it_airlines.second.getIcao() << std::endl;
        for(auto& it_rutas : it_airlines.second.getRutas()){
            std::cout << it_rutas->getCompany() << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

In that piece I'm entering an iteration that use 'it_airlines' to iterate over 'std::map airlines' which one return me correct data in the structure. After that, I tried to get the memory position of an element inserted before with the next fragment of code:

```
void VuelaFlight :: addNuevaRuta(const std::string &icao,                          
                                 const std::string &idAeroOrig,
                                 const std::string &idAerDest){
    Ruta ruta;
    if(this->airlines.lower_bound(icao) == this->airlines.end()){
        throw std::out_of_range("VuelaFlight :: addNuevaRuta -> No existe aerolinea con esa identificacion");
        return;
    }
    ruta.setCompany(&this->airlines.lower_bound(icao)->second);

    Aeropuerto airport;
    airport.setIata(idAeroOrig);

    auto it_airport = std::lower_bound(this->airports.begin(), this->airports.end(),airport);
    ruta.setOrigin(it_airport.base());

    airport.setIata(idAerDest);

    it_airport = std::lower_bound(this->airports.begin(), this->airports.end(),airport);
    ruta.setDestination(it_airport.base());

    this->airlines.lower_bound(icao)->second.linkAeroRuta(ruta);
    this->routes.push_back(ruta);
}
```

Following the method inside '.linkAeroRuta(Ruta& ruta)' from 'Aerolinea.h':

```
void Aerolinea::linkAeroRuta(Ruta &ruta) {
    this->aeroroutes.push_back(&ruta);
}
```

This two previous coming from this piece:

```
void VuelaFlight::cargaRutas(std::string &ficheroRutas) {
    std::ifstream is;
    std::stringstream columnas;
    std::string fila;

    std::string _icao = "";
    std::string _origin = "";
    std::string _destination = "";

    is.open(ficheroRutas); //carpeta de proyecto
    if (is.good()) {
        getline(is, fila); //primera _icao
        while (getline(is, fila)) {

            //¿Se ha leído una nueva fila?
            if (fila != "") {

                columnas.str(fila);

                //formato de fila: _icao;_origin;_destination

                getline(columnas, _icao, ';'); //leemos caracteres hasta encontrar y omitir ';'
                getline(columnas, _origin, ';');
                getline(columnas, _destination, ';');

                fila = "";
                columnas.clear();
                addNuevaRuta(_icao, _origin, _destination);
            }
        }

        is.close();

    } else {
        throw std::ifstream::failure("VuelaFlight :: cargaRutas-> Error de apertura en archivo");
    }
}
```

But all the memory positions are the same one, this would be the a little piece of the output with the previous code:

```
0MM
1CH
1QA
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
2CO
2K2
3FF
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
0xb419ffed40
```

Knowing that the airline 1QA has 19 routes and 3FF has 12 routes it means that the iterator iterate the exact number of elements that finds on aeroroutes correctly.

- This is the piece of the code where I try to access to an element inside of an element inside in the structure 'std::deque':

```
for(auto& it_airlines : this->airlines){
        std::cout << it_airlines.second.getIcao() << std::endl;
        for(auto& it_rutas : it_airlines.second.getRutas()){
            std::cout << it_rutas->getCompany()->getNombre() << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

In this case I try to enter into any attribute inside of the '.second' element but it return me a wrong output in the case of aeropuertos (airports) and aerolineas (airlines)

- Definition of '.getRutas' (attribute aeroutes is defined as 'std::deque<Ruta*> aeroroutes'):

```
std::deque<Ruta*> Aerolinea :: getRutas(){
    return this->aeroroutes;
}
```

When I try to access to the elements once it is nested in 'std::deque aeroroutes' in the method '.linkedAeroRutas' I get the correct data. In addition, when I try to access to the linked aeropuertos (airports) or aerolineas (airlines) by the 'std::list' it access without any problem. That's why I think the problem find on the access of the 'std::map' to the attribute 'std::deque aeroroutes' inside .second Aerolinea.

I tested the methods aforementionated '.linkAeroRuta(Ruta &ruta)' and 'addNuevaRuta(const std::string &icao, const std::string &idAeroOrig, const std::string &idAerDest)' and that two methods work, however the problem is still there.

Comment: `this->airlines.lower_bound(icao)->second.linkAeroRuta(ruta);` stores a pointer to a stack allocated object. When you use the pointer after `ruta` has gone out ouf scope you invoke undefined behavior

Comment: why do you store pointers?

Comment: please read about [mcve]. You posted far too much code and at the same time too little, because its only fragments, most declarations are missing

Comment: `this->aeroroutes.push_back(&ruta)` This is your problem right here. You are pushing an address of a local variable on some function. This address stops making sense as soon as the function returns.